# What does it mean for a vector to belong to the kernel of a set of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

if $ M_{2x2}(C) $ is a vector space and V which belongs to $ M_{2x2}(C) $ is a subset of all matrices A such that (1 2) belongs to the kernel(A). What does it mean for a vector to belong to the kernel of a set of matrices ? How would I express this ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

It means that for a matrix $A \in V$ we have:
$$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: does this mean the definition of kernel of is Av= 0?

Comment: Yes, the kerne of $A$ is the set of vectors such that $Ax=0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29